# How to replace http for https before DOM Construct on load KMZ file with ArcGIS API JS

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, jquery, dojo, angularjs

I have an application and it is loaded with https, this application loads a map with a KMZ file, and the content of that file has external reference to a PNG image that is loaded with http. This causes the page's https to break.

Look at this example of how this is done.

```
var kmlUrl = "https://s3.amazonaws.com/geodera-bucket/filesds/5c2e82457cd9e62b0a453ce3-1578081436616-bushfireAlert.kmz";
var kml = new KMLLayer(kmlUrl);
map.addLayer(kml);
kml.on("load", function() {
  domStyle.set("loading", "display", "none");
});
```

https://codepen.io/krekto/pen/NWPYmRb

I want to replace these http references with https before loading external content.

My application uses AngularJS, JQuery and Dojo, the solution can be with any of these technologies.

Comment: We're a little different from other sites. We're a Q&A site, not a discussion forum.  For questions that involve code we ask that you show us where you are stuck with your own code by including a [code snippet](http://meta.gis.stackexchange.com/questions/4312) in your question.  There is an [edit] button beneath your question which will enable you to do that and a **`{}`** button that enables you to format any highlighted code nicely.  Please check out our short [tour] for more about how the site works. Thanks.

Comment: Cross-posted as https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59675809/how-to-replace-http-for-https-before-dom-construct-on-load-kmz-file-with-arcgis

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about letting the browser do the work by adding this in the :

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" 
      content="upgrade-insecure-requests">
```

See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Security-Policy/upgrade-insecure-requests

Comment: thank you, solve the problem